# How to use Context object to get config values

Tags: magento2, configuration

I am getting this error after compiling in command prompt,

> Incorrect dependency in class ParadoxLabs\TokenBase\Helper\Data in
>
> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/ParadoxLabs/TokenBase/Helper/Data.php
>
> \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface already exists in context object
>
> \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in
>   context object

I have added scope config dependency in my helper.

But as it says, that it is already present in context, then how to use it to fetch config values.

Currently I am using this way to get config values

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('section/group/field');
```

Now how to access same, by using context object

Injection for my context object is

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
```

Answer (score 6):

If your helper extends `Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper` then **you don't need to add the `ScopeConfigInterface` dependency again in your constructor because the parent class already has that dependency.**

You can simply do:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('section/group/field');
```

Please note that the parent class variable does not start with an underscore.

**Same remark for the `Context` dependency**, you do not need to re add it as it's already part of the parent constructor.

FYI, the `AbstractHelper` constructor looks like this:

```
public function __construct(Context $context)
{
    $this->_moduleManager = $context->getModuleManager();
    $this->_logger = $context->getLogger();
    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    $this->_urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
    $this->_httpHeader = $context->getHttpHeader();
    $this->_eventManager = $context->getEventManager();
    $this->_remoteAddress = $context->getRemoteAddress();
    $this->_cacheConfig = $context->getCacheConfig();
    $this->urlEncoder = $context->getUrlEncoder();
    $this->urlDecoder = $context->getUrlDecoder();
    $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
}
```